# Python list 1 remove elements present in list 2

Tags: python

I have a python script with removes element from list1 if they are present in list2. Seems preety simple. This is what I did:

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
arr2 = [3,7,2,1,4,6]
for i in arr1:
    print i
    if i in arr2:
       arr1.remove(i)
       print arr1
```

**Expected Output**   `5`

**Got this**

```
1
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
3
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
5
6
[2, 4, 5, 7]  # final output
```

Even after printing i at each iteration I can't figure out why it skips 2 in the first place. But when I repeated the loop 3 times I got expected output.

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
arr2 = [3,7,2,1,4,6]
for i in arr1:
    print i
    if i in arr2:
       arr1.remove(i)
       print arr1
for i in arr1:
    print i
    if i in arr2:
       arr1.remove(i)
       print arr1
for i in arr1:
    print i
    if i in arr2:
       arr1.remove(i)
       print arr1
```

**Output**

```
1
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
3
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
5
6
[2, 4, 5, 7] 
2
[4, 5, 7]
5
7
[4, 5]
4
[5]
```

This gives me `5` as output in the final iteration. Can someone tell whats going here. And why it didn't remove all elements at first place and why I need to run them 3 times.

**Edit**
Although list comprehension worked:

```
arr1[:] = [x for x in arr1 if x not in arr2]
```

But why isn't my first code working. It is doing the same as what the list comprehension doing it

Comment: just to be clear will your list have any duplicate elements or not if yes then what you want to do. remove all or one?

Comment: I am looking for a more generic solution here. I am asking why 3 iteration instead of how to. Although I did it by the list comprehension way and it worked but why isn't it working in the traditional way

Comment: @Gahan it doesn't have duplicate elements. Although list2 has almost same number of elements as list1 and I just want to remove those elements from list1 which are present in list2. List comprehension worked `arr1[:] = [x for x in arr1 if x not in arr2]  ` but why isn't the traditional way working

Comment: list comprehension you commented is creating new list not removing from existing one

Comment: So you are suggesting instead of removing elements form existing one I should create a new list and append to it

Comment: @Gahan so I created a new list and append the element not in list2 to it and it worked. Maybe there was some referencing issue under the hood

Comment: the issue is you are iterating over list and removing item from same list. so while iteration if you remove first element it means 2 is considered as first element of list and second step of iteration it will skip 2 because the list you are iterating is modified.

Comment: @Gahan Exactly. That's why creating a new list worked. Now I got that

Answer (score -1):

for i in arr2:
    for j in arr1:
        if i in arr1:
            arr1.remove(i)
print(arr1)